# How to initialize stdout stdin with Qt 5.7

Tags: c++, qt, stdin, qdebug, qt5.7

I noticed something with qDebug() QTextStrean and generally stdin, stdout wanna ask, how it works actually, see this:

> **THIS WORKS!**

method **showmenu()** using QTextStream

```
showMenu(){
            QTextStream m_out(stdout);
            QTextStream m_in(stdin);

            m_out() << "Hey";
}
```

> **THIS DOESN'T WORK!**

**.h**

```
//declaration 

public:
   QTextStream m_out;
   QTextStream m_in;
```

**.cpp**

```
//method showMenu() 

showMenu(){
             m_out(stdout);
             m_in(stdin);

             m_out() << "Hey";
}
```

I noticed, it has problem with overloading, because also qDebug() uses stdout... am I correct?

It throws this error:

> 1>D:..\App_console.cpp(20,15): error : no match for
>   call to '(QTextStream) (_IO_FILE*&)'

I have included cstdio

What could it be?

Comment: In the first case you call a constructor. In the second case you try to call `operator()` that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre C++11, You will need to do that in your *Constructor Initialization List*.
In the Constructor Definition of your class, say `MyStreamer`, you can initialize it like this:

```
class MyStreamer{
....
public:
   QTextStream m_out;
   QTextStream m_in;
};
```

In your .cpp file:

```
MyStreamer::MyStreamer(...) : m_out(stdout), m_in(stdin) {
    ....
}
```

---

In C++11 and beyond, you could simply use *uniform initialization*:

```
class MyStreamer{
....
public:
   QTextStream m_out{stdout};
   QTextStream m_in{stdin};
};
```